# SQL Server Agent job to generate text file with date in file name causing error

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am newish to the BCP/CMD line thing and I get an error when I try to create a file. A little background info, I have a SQL Job that needs to run a stored procedure and output the results into a file using the BCP. The SQL Server job is executing the following command:

```
bcp "EXEC [DATABASE].[dbo].[STOREDPROC]" queryout c:\Temp\1234FLATVER4%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%000000.txt -c -t"|"  -T -S SERVER
```

The filename needs to look something like this:

```
1234FLATVER420190406000000.txt
```

I have tested the command and it works fine when I try output to a filename like: test.txt, but when I try to add the date, I get the following error:

> Unable to open BCP host data-file. Process Exit Code 1.

I was following this [website](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/date-in-bcp-out-file-name). I know the stored procedure is not the issue. FYI, I cannot use `xp_cmdshell` for security purposes.

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct offsets for getting the substring from dates? If any of them contain a `/` character the system may not allow to create a file because of an invalid name.

Comment: Is the bcp command you shared all that appears in the "command:" box in the details of your job step? If so, that wont work. The "command" you enter for the jobs step is exactly the same thing as executing that command at a command prompt.